# WP Filter to change the URL of an Anchor wrapping the last gallery image

Tags: filters, jquery, gallery

We have a normal WordPress gallery on a [development webpage](https://herodevelopment.com.au/allbathroomgear/design-build/bathrooms/).

[image]

The page is custom content through Advanced Custom Fields, and we are wrapping the section above's content like so:

```
<?php
  $content = get_sub_field('wysiwyg');
  if ( function_exists('slb_activate') ) {
    $content = slb_activate($content);
  }
  echo $content;
?>
```

The lightbox functionality is generated by [Simple Lightbox](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-lightbox/), and `slb_activate` is a function of this plugin, which adds the lightbox functionality to any gallery in the ACF content.

The designer wants the last image in the gallery (the purple one) to link to a different WordPress page while maintaining the lightbox functionality for the rest of the gallery.

I don't know if we need a WordPress filter (which to me would be complicated by the `slb_activate` function, or some jQuery, and target `.gallery-item:last-of-type`, replacing the URL with a new one?

If so, we'd like to take the page slug (bathrooms) from `https://herodevelopment.com.au/allbathroomgear/design-build/bathrooms/` and use this slug to generate a new URL of `https://herodevelopment.com.au/allbathroomgear/album/bathrooms/`

(so going from `/design-build/bathrooms/` to `/album/bathrooms/` on the final production website).

I'd appreciate any help, as I am unfortunately not a developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By javascript, You should replace the link on the last item with new one and change  tag's attribute, data-slb-active,  to "0".
Please use the following javascript.

jQuery("#gallery-1 .gallery-item:last-of-type a").attr("href", "https://herodevelopment.com.au/allbathroomgear/album/bathrooms/").attr("data-slb-active", "0");

Comment: Thanks very much Andre. You might want to wrap your comments in backticks to format it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the following:

```
<?php
$content = get_sub_field( 'wysiwyg' );
if ( function_exists( 'slb_activate' ) ) {
    $url_request = isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ?
        filter_var( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) :
        '';
    $url_path    = wp_parse_url( $url_request, PHP_URL_PATH );
    $url_path    = preg_replace( '#/.+/(.+)/#', '/album/$1/', $url_path );
    $content     = str_replace( '/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/gallery-thumb.jpg', $url_path, $content );
    $content     = slb_activate( $content );
}
echo $content;
?>
```